# Are Custom XML Elements allowed?

Tags: xml, xml-validation

Are custom Elements in XML allowed, f.e. `<foo>` or `<bar>`?

I want to create an XML-based Slider with HTML and JS and it's content should be editable through XML. There for I want to create an XML File with more than just Content. Transitiontypes and Transitionspeed should be defined in that. It might look similiar to the following:

```
<slider>
  <layer image="../path/to/image" fromoffset="-50,-50" tooffset="100,100" transition="moveup">
    <object image="../path/to/image" fromoffset="-50,-50" tooffset="100,100" transition="moveright"></object>
    // The Object could be an image moving into the image
  </layer>
</slider>
```

Is there anything to consider?

Comment: That's the **eXtensible** Markup Language!

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but I found http://www.rpbourret.com/xml/xmldtd.htm to be helpful for declaring your own doctype. It is also important to note, there are other options for doing so. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Definition#XML_DTDs_and_schema_validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML is a toolkit for building markup languages (with the elements and attributes that the designer wishes).

If you are designing the language, you can add whatever elements you like.

If you are not, then you can look to [namespaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) to create a document consisting of bits from different markup languages (the one you started working with, and the one with the new elements and attributes that you invented).

Either way, the software that processes the XML will have to be written so it can handle what you are producing.

Answer (score 2):

Custom elements are allowed in XML, but in HTML "it all depends". You might find this link useful:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_XML_Data_Islands_in_Mozilla

Comment: XML data islands were a Microsoft invention that were [removed in IE 10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/hh801224(v=vs.85).aspx). I wouldn't go near them.